# How to stop/pause thread upon main thread/Activity paused/stopped in android ?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

In my app, I want to stop a thread [ just a loop to print ], created while on main activity onCreate.
and works fine. as expected,

but,I want to stop the same Created thread while main thread/activity goes to pause or stop. as an user case for interrupt.

How to handle the created thread ?

Comment: try this-> getActivity().getMainLooper().getThread().join(2000);

Comment: what we are trying to do with the above line code.?  where we need to place this code,- onCreate  or in main thread or in child thread.

Answer (score 0):

```
getActivity().getMainLooper().getThread().join(2000);
```

The above itself works on main thread. Try it below the line of code where you want to pause your main thread. For example I want to call a function "Onclicked()" on Button click and some part of that function needs to execute while UI Thread is paused. so I will write above line of code. Sample Code :-

```
((ContainerBaseFragmentActivity) getActivity()).addProductToCart(product, mArrayListCartItemAttributes, price, true);  // line Which will pause UI Thread.
try
{                                 
    getActivity().getMainLooper().getThread().join(2000);
}
catch(InterruptedException e)
{
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```